# Layers and keyframes not showing in Summary

Tags: 2d, layers, viewlayers

Why are the layers not showing up under the *Summary* tab?

I have tried to find out for hours, but i can seem to figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please click on the green coloured button which is located to the right of stroke under **collection** to show the layers under **summary**.

And the image below  is taken from Blender v3.1.2

[image: From v3.1.2]